# What does " appears casual" means in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have a paragraph:

> You have to clearly show your true intentions at some point when talking to a woman you want to make it obvious that you are interested in her on a romantic or sexual level. The most confident and therefore best way to make your interest clear is to actually tell women that you are attracted to and interested in them [...]
>   It is brilliant for a man to be so confident that he **appears casual**, but that does not mean it is a good idea for him to strike up a casual conversation and hide his intentions. Anyone can strike up a casual conversation about nothing of importance, and males can often do so with confidence, but as soon as they want to flirt, their confidence vanishes

I don't know what does "appears casual" mean in this paragraph? Does it mean "dress casually"?

Comment: In this context, it means *relaxed*.

Comment: I don't think this should be closed - the asker has given us their best guess as to what it means but it doesn't make sense in this context. I don't think a dictionary is going to help here, because it is apparent that the asker understands the individual meanings of appear and casual. It's just not clear exactly what they mean together (even though it might be obvious to someone who is fluent).

Answer (score 3):

In this context it means "appears to be unconcerned about the outcome".  Another way to express it is simply "cool", a word that can have many meanings, one of which is "unconcerned, feeling no stress about the situation".

The author of the paragraph is trying to say that *anyone* can be "cool" when talking to women -- but at some point you have to express actual interest, at which point many men lose their composure.